# Linux Kernel Timer function pass custom pointer data

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I'm trying to use the Linux kernel timers for the first time, and I'm trying to pass in a pointer as function parameter but any method I used keeps crashing my 3.12 kernel.

Here is what I have:

```
init (struct lis3lv02d *lis3) {

    printk("Timer module installing\n");
    setup_timer( &poll_timer, accel_chip_poll, 0 );
    poll_timer.data=(unsigned long) lis3;
    ret = mod_timer( &poll_timer, jiffies + msecs_to_jiffies(POLL_MSECS) );
}



accel_chip_poll(unsigned long data) {
    struct lis3lv02d *lis3 = (struct lis3lv02d*)data;
    get_data (stacc3);
    ...
}
```

It constantly crashes my kernel (module is built-in).
Can someone please help me figure out what I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Looking at [existing](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/sysrq.c?v=3.12#L885) [examples](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/sysrq.c?v=3.12#L630), your code seems mostly correct (other than that your timer function should return void). I assume that `poll_timer` is declared as static, is this correct? if so, you might want to verify the validity of your data pointer, i.e. is `lis3` really pointing to valid memory belonging to your struct.

Comment: Your code looks good. I had a similar problem because I was accessing i2c from the timer. Perhaps there is a context issue.

Answer (score 0):

In accel_chip_poll. You are casting a long value (data) to a pointer to structure (and as per standard the behaviour is undefined). You probably want to cast a pointer to data like the following:

struct lis3lv02d *lis3 = (struct lis3lv02d*)&data;

And the same holds for:

poll_timer.data=(unsigned long) lis3;

You need to dereference it first, please check how to access structure elements via pointer.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. His code is correct. Yours is not. TTake a look at some examples in the kernel as shown by the first comment in the question.